# Processing Only One Image Uses All of Ram

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am running this code in google colab (I also tried at my local). I use only one image and it uses all of the ram. Do I do something wrong? Is it normal to use 16 gb ram? I added %matplotlib inline and it still crashes?

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

f = cv2.imread('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/grass.png')
f = cv2.cvtColor(f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).astype(float)

plt.imshow(f)
plt.colorbar()

def gauss1(sigma, width):
    
    hwidth = round((width-1)/2)
    x = np.arange(-hwidth, hwidth+1,1)
    
    g = np.exp(-x**2/(2*sigma**2))
    return g/np.sum(g)
    
    
g1=gauss1(2,11)
g1=np.reshape(g1,(1,-1))
plt.imshow(g1)

f1 = cv2.filter2D(f,-1,g1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20))
fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(f)
fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(f1)
```

It does not even produce last code snippet's output.

Comment: Use `plt.show()` for the output or `%matplotlib inline` if your are using jupyter notebook environment.

Comment: will this solve the problem for colab too

Comment: Yes, add `%matplotlib inline` after your imports as colab is a notebook environment and it will show the output.

Comment: Otherwise, you can just add `plt.show()` after at the end of your code block if you just need to show that one. `%matplotlib inline` would work for whole notebook.

Comment: I added %matplotlib inline and it still crashes

Answer (score 0):

Use:

- If you're using terminal/console, use `plt.show()` to show the matplotlib output.
- Use `%matplotlib inline` if you are using any ipython notebook kernel such as jupyter notebooks, google colab or kaggle notebooks.

Comment: I added %matplotlib inline but it still crashes

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Checkout [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SC_YBK95_qemOwGVCBbg1H5FpUUjZoFh?usp=sharing). It is working fine. Check if your image is valid. I used a local image from my computer.

Comment: how much ram does it use when you run it

Comment: 0.78 GB, I would suggest you restart your runtime and try again. Did you try out the notebook I shared? You can run it and see how it works.

Comment: thank you very much, I just realized that my image was problematic. i tried with another image and it worked well. thank you.

Comment: Told you its working fine. Always try with other inputs to cross check if something is wrong at your end. Happy to help!